# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running Android JUnit test

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, build-process, noclassdeffounderror

[image: Project Hierarchies]

I've three projects in workspace: **Common, Client and Server**.

**Common:** The classes are used in both Client and Server project.

Now, Common project contains a Class **User**

However when I run the Client-test, it gives me

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.org.example.common.model.User
```

**Please Note:**

1. I've added Common to the build path of Client and have marked it in "Order and Export" tab also.
2. Also, exported Common from Client project.

**UPDATE:** It also gives me the same error when I create the User object in Client project.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

The problem was that Android dependencies in my Client project were not being updated. This prevented classes from being added to build path.

**Steps to solve the issue:**

1. Right Click on Android Dependencies in the Client Project > Build Path > Remove from Build Path.
2. Right Click on the Client Project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.